# mySQL "REPLACE INTO" : is it having any effect in this case

Tags: mysql

I'm charged with porting some old code to a new platform and I'm looking at a bit that has me pretty puzzled. I *think* I'm familiar with what REPLACE INTO does, but this leaves me feeling unsure. The mySQL query is:

```
REPLACE INTO theTable SET value1 = ?, value2 = ?
```

My understanding is this only has an effect if those columns are defined as unique. The table definition for theTable looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `theTable` (
  `value1` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `value2` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `value1` (`value2`),
  KEY `value2` (`value2`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

I've inserted a row that's an exact duplicate of an existing row and had nothing happen ( a new row was inserted, the old row still exists ) ... am I missing something or did the original developer just do something that was completely useless?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From MySQL manual:

> REPLACE works exactly like INSERT,
>   except that if an old row in the table
>   has the same value as a new row for a
>   PRIMARY KEY or a UNIQUE index, the old
>   row is deleted before the new row is
>   inserted...
>
> ... **Note that unless the table has a
>   PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE index,** using a
>   REPLACE statement makes no sense. It
>   becomes equivalent to INSERT, because
>   there is no index to be used to
>   determine whether a new row duplicates
>   another.

So you need to add `UNIQUE KEY` in order for it to work.

Answer (score 3):

Like you said: it will only replace (in fact delete + insert) row, if UNIQUE constraint is in place. In your table there is none.